# Preventing duplicate data Entry of The client Id and the Borrower Names in my laravel project

Tags: laravel

How to prevent duplicate data Entry with unique number in my database. here is my controllers code[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1bNG.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use Laravel validate method, this will give you an error if unique_number exists before storing the data in the database.

```
$request->validate(['unique_number' => ['unique:borrowers']]);
```